# Update records from datagridview

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpTFm.jpg)

I am working on "cash payment" module

And here I am entering 5 accounts which will be debit after I save it. Now I am using below code that will update all accounts at ones but can you check what mistake I'm doing because this code is not working it saving the record but not hitting the accounts

I tried below code:

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In CashpaymentDataGridView.Rows
            If Not row.IsNewRow Then
                con = New SqlConnection(appx.myconnection)
                con.Open()
                Dim ctx As String = "select Account_Title from COA where Account_Title=@d1 and Account_Title=@d2"
                cmd = New SqlCommand(ctx)
                cmd.Connection = con
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1", row.Cells(3).Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", row.Cells(5).Value)
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                If (rdr.Read()) Then

                    con = New SqlConnection(appx.myconnection)
                    con.Open()
                    Dim cb2 As String = "Update COA set opening_balance = opening_balance + " & row.Cells(3).Value & " where AccountID=@d1"
                    Dim cb3 As String = "Update COA set opening_balance = opening_balance - " & row.Cells(5).Value & " where AccountID=@d2"
                    cmd = New SqlCommand(cb2 And cb3)
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1", (row.Cells(3).Value))
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", row.Cells(5).Value)
                    cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    con.Close()
                End If
            End If
```

### Update

Now here COA FROM AND PAYMENT FROM are CASH IN ACCOUNT account which will be credit by total amount

COA TO AND PAYMENT TO are debit accounts which will be debit by actual amount

COA TO AND COA FROM are the COA ACCOUNT ID  and vb code will update both according to COA ACCOUNT ID NUMBER

So when user press SAVE, all account ID under COA FROM which is default cash in hand will get credit by actual value

And all account ID under COA To Will get debit to actual amount but not with total

Example entry

```
coa id                      description                           dr             cr                total

30141                        test account supplier            5000                

       30162                        cash in hand                              5000                  5000

30141                        test account other            5000                

       30162                        cash in hand                              5000                  5000

30141                        test new                              5000                

       30162                        cash in hand                              5000                  5000
```

Now total of all entries which will be credit to cash in hand is 15000 and with vb code 5000 of each account will be debited when user will press save and it will be done by using COA TO column in datagridview.

Comment: According to the code both your accountID and openingBalance is being determined by `row.Cells(3).Value` and `row.Cells(5).Value` ? what is the value of `cb2` and `cb3` when debugging? Right click -> quick watch on the variables to see what values you're actually passing to SQL server

Comment: cb2 and cb3 are sqlcommand and i know my code is not working thats why i ask for help to please modify my code accordingly.

Comment: You're not specifying if you're receiving any errors so the issue has to be with your SQL. If you check the value of the variable and paste it in SQL is it having the desired effect?